# PHP: Using a variable that are inside a function

Tags: php

I have:

```
include ('functions.php');
check_blocked();
echo $blocked;
```

in functions.php, check_blocked(); exists. Inside check_blocked I got:

```
global $blocked;
$blocked = '1234';
```

I want to echo $blocked variable, that are inside check_blocked().

It doesnt work, no output..

This is an example of my original problem, so please dont say that I could just have the echo inside the function, as I cannot have in my original code.

Comment: Try using [`$GLOBALS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) instead and see if that helps.

Comment: why are all of you encouraging him to use globals, when he should just return the value from the function??

Comment: Return $blocked? So that 'echo check_blocked()' actually works? If there are multiple $blocked, then use arrays. Where's the problem?

Comment: @dqhendricks Crazy how 18 seconds can matter...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should look like

```
$blocked = 0;
include('functions.php');
check_blocked();
echo $blocked;
```

With functions.php looking like

```
function check_blocked(){
     global $blocked;
     $blocked = 1234;
}
```

You must define blocked outside of the scope of the function before you global blocked into the function.

Comment: +1. Indeed. Otherwise the `global $blocked` in the function doesn't do anything; it doesn't find a global named `$blocked` because you did not make one yet!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal upvoting the use of globals? why not just return the value from the function?

Comment: @charlie If you run it, it will echo 1234 because your now in the proper scope.  Had $blocked not been set to zero, then you would see nothing.  If $blocked was echoed before the check_blocked(); function was called, then you would see zero.

Comment: @dqhendricks That could possibly be a superior approach (depending on the actual scenario behind the testcase). However, this answer is a correct response to the question asked, identifying the specific code mistake committed by the OP.

Comment: There are 100 ways to skin a cat, this answer actually answers the question asked about scope of variables.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just returning the value?

```
function check_blocked() {
    $blocked = '1234';
    return $blocked;
}
```

then

```
include ('functions.php');
echo check_blocked();
```

Avoid globales wherever possible.

Comment: +1. Globals should be avoided. This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @mfonda There is no single "correct" way to do anything, and sweeping generalisations don't help.

Comment: We don't know enough about the real-life scenario behind his testcase. This may in fact not be appropriate; I feel that you diverged too far from the original testcase. No downvote, though.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Well that is why I asked (;)). I agree, to give a more appropriate answer we would need more information. Anyway, it is always good to show other possibilities imo.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the variable is declared outside of the check_blocked() function, you can't.

```
$foo = null;

function check_blocked() {
   global $foo;
   $foo = "Hello";
   // do some stuff
}

global $foo;
echo $foo; // prints "Hello"
```

If its defined inside the function like:

```
function check_blocked() {
    global $foo;
    $foo = "Hello";
    // other work
}


global $foo;
echo $foo; // Nothing
```

then the variable is scoped locally, and is discarded as soon as the function completed.

Comment: ) Happens to us all. If you also add it to the second example, and explain why it no longer works properly (which is what this question is all about), then I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `check_blocked()` to return `$blocked` or you can try use:

```
include ('functions.php');
check_blocked();
global $blocked;
echo $blocked;
```

Comment: -1. Eh? That's already in global scope. Why write `global` there? What nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

instead, use a return value. globals are bad.

```
include ('functions.php');
echo check_blocked();

function check_blocked() {
    return '1234';
}
```

Comment: Though a valid way to do things, doesn't push the point of variable scope and how to actually use a global variable.

Comment: @Geoffrey Wagner he doesn't actually ask anything about globals or scope... the OPs question was how to echo a variable that is created within a function after the function has executed. why not help them to understand the best method?

Comment: i see your point completely and i am not devaluing, but why not show them the errors of their ways instead of saying, just do it this way??  Teach a man to fish and feed him forever IMO